# ASP.NET App Deploying on Azure - Error 500 -

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure

1. Link to GitHub: https://github.com/dimiporf/Dim_MVC
2. I get an error:

   > Exception:
   > System.InvalidOperationException: The view 'Details' was not found. The following locations were searched:
   > /Areas/Customer/Views/Home/Details.cshtml
   > /Areas/Customer/Views/Shared/Details.cshtml
   > /Views/Shared/Details.cshtml
   > /Pages/Shared/Details.cshtml
3. On page `https://dimweb.azurewebsites.net/Customer/Home/Details?productId=1`
4. I checked my localhost version of the app, runs smooth as a butter. I triple-checked the permissions on Azure database, and made sure it allows azure to do its magic, as its mentioned on video of deployment.

Also tried chatGPT, YouTube etc. for similar problems, I only found there solutions to the same error (500) when app won't start.

My app starts, logs in, modifies the products and the categories, also in database and on site, but when I try to enter details of ANY product, it throws an exception.

So it is different and I cannot debug it cause I am a noob on Azure, and it runs perfectly fine locally

Comment: The error message is straightforward - it's saying the `Details.cshtml` file doesn't exist - no-one is saying anything about permissions...

Comment: Is your Issue resolved ?

Comment: But it exists locally - And works fine - No, I have no clue how to resolve this issue

Comment: Your GitHub repo does not have the mentioned views.Try to push the local code to GitHub again and check once.